# WSO2 - using identity server 6.1.0 as federated identity server of api manager 4.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am working on this documentation tutorial:

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/sso/configuring-identity-server-as-external-idp-using-oidc/

This is to be able to login using the identity server users from the api manager publisher, devportal, and api consumption.

When i tested, i was redirected to the identity server login page, but when i login i get the following error: "Suspicious authentication attempts found Suspicious login attempts found during the authentication process. Please try signing in again"

The i tried to add the following to deployment.toml of both IS and API Manager:

> [session.nonce.cookie]
> enabled="false"

So now after login i am redirected to a page saying: You have successfully logged out.
And in the apim logs i can see this error:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler} - Authentication failed exception! javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
```

To note that i am using the default certificate for both and i am using localhost.com as domain. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This could be because the default certificates in IS and APIM are different. For testing purposes, you could try to use the wso2carbon.jks and client-truststore from one product in both both products (copy and replace in the other product). But you might have to do a fresh setup in this case.

Other option would be to import the certificate of APIM to IS truststore and IS cert to APIM truststore.

Comment: thank you this moved my problem from certificate issue to a blank page after writing the username and password and clicking on the login page. the last url printed in the browser is: https://apim.wso2.com:9443/publisher/services/auth/callback/login?code=cb7868dc-2dc3-3fe2-9c22-be0d5333c106&state=12e44427-0a46-4414-a96b-2b8c1ae289ac%2COIDC&session_state=837f3e3b5ef6f356f4e5cbf88bbc27e03a66e3c1b882ecbde22518675bd474d6.miKHm_QAzjRFXOP6YVdZuw  And calling this url from postman returns 200 http status code. In the inspect browser option, the only error that is displayed is on favicon.ico http 403